# How to sum consecutive highlighted cells within the same column?

Tags: excel

I have a table looks likes this:

[image]

How can I sum the consecutive green cells within the same column? So I will get something like this, where the consecutive rows are merged after the sum:

[image]

My conditional formatting rule is value `>0` turns green and values `<0` turns red. I want to compute results from column `H` only. I have tried using the code below but didn't work.

`=SUMIFS(H4:H8763, "<0",H5:H8764,">0")`

Comment: can it be on the last line of the grouping?

Comment: what do you mean? or can you show me how your approach works?

Comment: Right now you show it on the 2nd row of the group of three, can it be on the last row of the grouping, in this case the third.

Comment: will they still look the same as the picture shows? If yes, then it can

Comment: the value would be on the row beneath what is showing.

Comment: if the value stays the same as the picture shows, then it doesn't matter on which position lies within the merged cell

Comment: oh, I did not realize it is a merged cell.  You will need vba to merge and unmerge based on the values in column H.

Comment: oh I see, but your answer did work on my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not mind not having merged cells, put this in I4:

```
=IF(AND($H4>0,OR($H5<0,$H5="")),SUMIFS($H$4:$H4,$H$4:$H4,">0")-SUM($I$3:$I3),"")
```

And drag it down the length of the data.

[image: ![enter image description here]